# IIS 7.5 url rewriting help - weird querystring

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an inbound link that has a lot of garbage in it. My site just loads the home page and ignores the querystring, but I'd like to detect the querystring and redirect to a clean home url.

The url looks like this:

http://www.mysite.url/?c%253E'dmjdlgsbve%253E2'lfzxpset%253E'sbol%253E2'f%253E'vsm%253Eiuuq%253B00xxx%252Fopdmjdlz%252Fdpn0'gffe%253Eopqbz'qsjdf%253E'tbq%253Ebd7g8g73cc3c7d%253Af5925f3efd2f62dcd'zbsht%253Exxx%252Fopdmjdlz%252Fdpn

I can't seem to make a rule that catches this querystring and let me redirect to http://www.mysite.url. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do. First of all you have to make sure you are on the homepage (i.e. empty request URL) and then you check for a non empty query string in the conditions. If both are the case, you do a permanent redirect back to the same URL (= URI without query string).

Like:

```
<rule name="Remove query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{URL}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

If you want you could add a more specific condition to let it only match this specific inbound link.

UPDATE:
I suspect that there is some double URL encoding going on in your URL. For example, %253E is probably ment to be %3E as %25 is the percentage sign URL encoded. And %3E is the > character URL encoded. So I think you will have more luck with this:

```
<rule name="Remove query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^c%3E'dmjdlgsbve%3E2'lfzxpset%3E'sbol%3E2'f%3E'vsm%3Eiuuq;00xxx/opdmjdlz/dpn0'gffe%3Eopqbz'qsjdf%3E'tbq%3Ebd7g8g73cc3c7d:f5925f3efd2f62dcd'zbsht%3Exxx/opdmjdlz/dpn$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{URL}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I'm wanting to detect just this particular querystring though, but it seems like some of the characters in it are throwing off the filter... like the percent sign and some others. I'd like to leave other querystrings intact.